# Treating Medieval text/poem's name according to Chicago

Tags: punctuation, orthography

Republishing a work from the '50s where the author references a medieval text, a poem, with a Latin title that is otherwise written in Middle English, and now must present it in a manner that conforms to Chicago. In this case, what exactly to do with italics, translated title, capitalization, and quotation marks is unclear. The poem is relatively obscure, and is known by at least a couple names, but in the text he refers to it like this:

**The architects of medieval England were simple masons but they harbored erudite aspiration and called their rules 'Constitutiones Artis Geometriae Secundum Euclidem' (Regulations of Geometrical Art According to Euclid).**

My inclination, after reading CMOS sections, is to use sentence case (capitalizing the beginning and proper nouns only) and to put the Latin title in italics. However, it's a poem, not a book title, so therefore in quotation marks, or should it be both italics and quotations? And then the following translation, in parentheses... the text was brought into modern English some five centuries later, and with a rather different title at times, but here the author is giving a translation that is word-for-word from the Latin title, so what to do?

Should it be this?

**...and called their rules "*Constitutiones artis geometriae secundum Euclidem*" ("Regulations of geometrical art according to Euclid") ?**

Comment: You seem to be muddling a name for a set of rules with a name for a poem; the two have different formats. You could rewrite so it's one or the other.

Comment: It is indeed a set of regulations given in poetic form, one of the earliest known texts associated with freemasonary, and does not conform to conventions we're familiar with in later eras. http://www.durandlodge.com/books/RegiusMs1390.pdf
It's also referred to as the "Regius Manuscript" or the "Haliwell Mansucript," depending on context. The author who cites it in 1953 was versed in Latin and opts to use the title above, though it is sometimes also given as  "Constituciones artis gemetriae secundum Euclydem." The texts are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masonic_manuscripts

Comment: Maybe ask your library if they can get a book on Medieval Swordsmanship which, on the face of it, may have the same issues. The Royal Armouries copy of document I.33 or Guy Windsor's books on Fiore or Armazare maybe.  Guy has a free download on Fiore here in case it helps any.  https://guywindsor.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/The-Fiore-Translation-Project-Print.pdf

Comment: Also in case it helps, look for works on "Lament for the makaris" by William Dunbar. It's written in Scots but every 4th line is the Latin "Timor mortis conturbat me".  The titles translates to English as Lament for the Makers/Poets.